# Why isn't my while loop inside a for loop working?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

So I'm relatively new to Python (2.7). I wrote a code for synthetic division, and it involves a while loop inside a for loop, but when I execute the .py file in the terminal, it displays "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" pointing to the while loop line.

Here's the code:

```
for div in rootlist:
        dex = 1
        quot = [poly[0]]
    while dex != len(poly):
        quot.append(poly[dex] + quot[dex - 1] * div)
        dex = dex + 1
```

Why oh why? :(

Comment: How does it not work? SyntaxError? Then, indent correctly.

Comment: its because of `while` indentation !

Answer (score 2):

In python, [indentation matters](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation). Your code should be:

```
for div in rootlist:
    dex = 1
    quot = [poly[0]]
    while dex != len(poly):
        quot.append(poly[dex] + quot[dex - 1] * div)
        dex = dex + 1
```